# Interactive bash script to create new permanent swapfiles

Tags: bash, linux

I started self-learning Bash scripting yesterday, and I finished my first successful "advance" script.

## Goal

To create an interactive step-by-step script to that allowed customizing various parts of the process of creating permanent swapfiles. I based my idea off of **Ask Ubuntu** Answer's [#1](https://askubuntu.com/a/1039179/782513) and [#2](https://askubuntu.com/a/1049496/782513).

## Background

While creating it, I extended ideas such as allowing exiting from the script at any time and formatting the output.

You will see that I use different styles throughout the code (i.e. case vs if-elif-else, etc...). That deals with me learning as I coded, and having issues trying to get the syntax right while learning. I want to consolidate my different styles - probably into cases.

## Additional Concerns I have

I know that all of you will suggest any issues that you see, and I will be happy about that; however, I am curious about a few things.

1. Is this code portable? [Edit] Mostly anyone with a Linux Distro should be able to use this script.
2. I put a lot of effort into formatting the output and making it look easy to read. I tried to separate the output of my code vs the output of other commands (i.e. adding `>>` and`>>>>`). Is it good enough? Would you suggest anything else? etc?

## Possible Extensions

The code works as intended; however, I do plan on extending it in the future. These could affect possible responses - some response might make these harder or easier to implement, or they might have no effect at all. Anyways, if I extend the code later on to accommodate more use-cases, these are what I believe I could do in the future:

1. Allow a non-interactive script mode that uses arguments for customizations
2. Allow single/batch removal of swapfiles.
3. Allow easier testing of each pathway of the interactive script
4. Allow color and bold support.

---

## Code

> **GitHub Repo** at [ciscorucinski/Swapfile-Utils](https://github.com/ciscorucinski/Swapfile-Utils/)
>
> **For *unmodified code*, check out the Protected Branch at [`1_200606_StackExchange-CodeReview`](https://github.com/ciscorucinski/Swapfile-Utils/tree/1_200606_StackExchange-CodeReview)**
>
> *Note: Only the variable declaration of `help_text` on the GitHub link is different due to a mistake on my side. No escaped tabs and newlines in GitHub*
>
> **For *updated code*, check out the Development Branch at [`develop`](https://github.com/ciscorucinski/Swapfile-Utils/tree/develop)**

```
#!/bin/bash

help_text="/n>> Documentation:\n\n\t

Usage: $(basename "$0") [-h]\n\t 
Creates a new permanent swapfile\n\n\t
where:\n\t\t
    -h  displays help text"


ask_for_size_allocation="
>>>> Amount to allocate for new swapfile? (default: 4G) : "

ask_for_swapfile_name="
>>>> Filename for new swapfile? (default: '/swapfile') : "

line="# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #"

shopt -s extglob

case $1 in
    ?(-)@(-h|-help) )
        echo -e help_text
        ;;
esac

retry=true
while $retry; do
    echo -e -n ">>>> Are you sure you want to create a new swapfile? (Y / N):"
    read yes_no
    case $yes_no in
        [Yy]|[Yy][Ee][Ss] )

            echo -e "\n$line"
            echo -e "Current Swapfiles:\n"
            sudo swapon -s 
            echo -e "$line"
            retry=false
            ;;
        [Nn]|[Nn][Oo]|[Qq][Uu][Ii][Tt] )
            echo -e ">> Exiting..."
            exit 0
            ;;
        * )
            echo -e ">> Error: invalid response\n"
            retry=true
    esac
done

echo -e ""
echo -e ">> Step 1: Size Allocation"
echo -e -n $ask_for_size_allocation
read swap_size

if [ -z "${swap_size}" ]; then
    swap_size="4G"
elif [[ $swap_size =~ [1-9][0-9]*[mMgG] ]]; then
    :
elif [[ $swap_size =~ [Qq][Uu][Ii][Tt] ]]; then
    echo -e ">> Exiting..."
    exit 0
else
    echo -e ">> Invalid Size: ${swap_size^^}. Exiting..."
    exit 1
fi

echo -e ""
echo -e ">> Step 2: File Name"
echo -e -n $ask_for_swapfile_name
read swap_name

if [ -z "${swap_name}" ]; then
    swap_name="/swapfile"
elif [[ $swap_size =~ [Qq][Uu][Ii][Tt] ]]; then
    echo -e ">> Exiting..."
    exit 0
elif [[ $swap_name =~ [/]+([0-9a-zA-Z]|[_-]) ]]; then
    :
elif [[ $swap_name =~ [+([0-9a-zA-Z]|[_-])] ]]; then 
    swap_name="/$swap_name" 
else
    echo -e ">> Invalid Pattern: $swap_name. Exiting..."
    exit 1
fi

echo -e ""
echo -e -n ">>>> Continue? '$swap_name' (${swap_size^^}) will be created. (Y / N):"
read yes_no
case $yes_no in
    [Yy]|[Yy][Ee][Ss] )
        echo -e""
        echo -e ">> 1. Creating swapfile..."

        echo -e ""
        echo -e "$line"

        sudo fallocate -l $swap_size $swap_name
        sudo chmod 600 $swap_name
        sudo mkswap $swap_name

        echo -e "$line"
        echo -e ""

        echo -e ">> 2. Enabling swapfile..."
        sudo swapon $swap_name

        echo -e ">> 3. Swapfile added."
        echo -e ""
        echo -e "$line"
        echo -e "Current Swapfiles:"
        echo -e ""
        sudo swapon -s 
        echo -e "$line"
        echo -e ""
        ;;
    [Qq][Uu][Ii][Tt]|[Nn]|[Nn][Oo]|[*])
        echo -e ">> Exiting..."
        exit 0
        ;;
esac

echo -e -n ">>>> Make swapfile permanent? (Y / N):"
read yes_no

case $yes_no in
    [Yy]|[Yy][Ee][Ss] )

        echo -e "$swap_name none swap sw 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab > /dev/null

        echo -e ""
        echo -e ">> 4. Created permanent swapfile. Modified '/etc/fstab'"

        echo -e -n ">>>> Do you want to view '/etc/fstab?' (Y / N):"
            read yes_no

            case $yes_no in
                [Yy]|[Yy][Ee][Ss] )

                    lenght=${#swap_name}
                    echo -e ""
                    echo -e "$line"
                    cat /etc/fstab 
                    echo -e "$line"
                    ;;
                *)
                    echo -e ">> Exiting..."
                    exit 0
                    ;;
            esac
        ;;
    [Qq][Uu][Ii][Tt] )
        echo -e ">> Exiting..."
        exit 0  
        ;;
    *)
        echo -e ">> 4. Created temp swapfile."
        echo -e ">> Exiting..."
        exit 0
        ;;
esac

shopt -u extglob
```

## Output

```
$ bash new_swapfile.sh
>>>> Are you sure you want to create a new swapfile? (Y / N):y

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
Current Swapfiles:

[sudo] password for ciscorucinski: 
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile_ext3                          file        262140  238384  -5
/swapfile_ext7                          file        131068  106376  -3
/swapfile                               file        8388604 476148  -6
/swapfile_ext6                          file        131068  68840   -4
/swapfile_ext5                          file        131068  115304  -2
/dev/dm-1                               partition   1003516 0   -7
/swapfile_ext8                          file        131068  0   -8
/swapfile_ext9                          file        131068  0   -9
/swapfile_ext10                         file        131068  0   -10
/swapfile_ext11                         file        131068  0   -11
/swapfile_ext12                         file        131068  0   -12
/swapfile_ext13                         file        131068  0   -13
/swapfile_ext                           file        524284  0   -14
/swapfile_ext14                         file        131068  0   -15
/swapfile_ext15                         file        131068  0   -16
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

>> Step 1: Size Allocation
>>>> Amount to allocate for new swapfile? (default: 4G) :128m

>> Step 2: File Name
>>>> Filename for new swapfile? (default: '/swapfile') :/swapfile_ext16

>>>> Continue? '/swapfile_ext16' (128M) will be created. (Y / N):y

>> 1. Creating swapfile...

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 128 MiB (134213632 bytes)
no label, UUID=94e452f1-b252-4ea2-8d5f-e23634e34081
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

>> 2. Enabling swapfile...
>> 3. Swapfile added.

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
Current Swapfiles:

Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile_ext3                          file        262140  238384  -5
/swapfile_ext7                          file        131068  106376  -3
/swapfile                               file        8388604 476148  -6
/swapfile_ext6                          file        131068  68840   -4
/swapfile_ext5                          file        131068  115304  -2
/dev/dm-1                               partition   1003516 0   -7
/swapfile_ext8                          file        131068  0   -8
/swapfile_ext9                          file        131068  0   -9
/swapfile_ext10                         file        131068  0   -10
/swapfile_ext11                         file        131068  0   -11
/swapfile_ext12                         file        131068  0   -12
/swapfile_ext13                         file        131068  0   -13
/swapfile_ext                           file        524284  0   -14
/swapfile_ext14                         file        131068  0   -15
/swapfile_ext15                         file        131068  0   -16
/swapfile_ext16                         file        131068  0   -17
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

>>>> Make swapfile permanent? (Y / N):y

>> 4. Created permanent swapfile. Modified '/etc/fstab'
>>>> Do you want to view '/etc/fstab?' (Y / N):y

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=D6C3-F1E1  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
/swapfile_ext3 none swap sw 0 0
/swapfile_ext5 none swap sw 0 0
/swapfile_ext6 none swap sw 0 0
/swapfile_ext7 none swap sw 0 0
/swapfile_ext8 none swap sw 0 0
/swapfile_ext9 none swap sw 0 0
/swapfile_ext10 none swap sw 0 0
/swapfile_ext11 none swap sw 0 0
/swapfile_ext13 none swap sw 0 0
/swapfile_ext14 none swap sw 0 0
/swapfile_ext15 none swap sw 0 0
/swapfile_ext16 none swap sw 0 0
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `fallocate` and swap files

You should not use `fallocate` for creating swap files. It's not supported.

From [the `mkswap` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/mkswap.8.html):

```
Note  that  a  swap  file  must  not contain any holes.  Using cp(1) to
create the file is not acceptable.  Neither is use of  fallocate(1)  on
file  systems  that support preallocated files, such as XFS or ext4, or
on copy-on-write filesystems like btrfs.   It  is  recommended  to  use
dd(1)  and  /dev/zero in these cases.  Please read notes from swapon(8)
before adding a swap file to copy-on-write filesystems.
```

And from [the `swapon` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/swapon.8.html):

```
You should not use swapon on a file with holes.  This can  be  seen  in
the system log as

      swapon: swapfile has holes.

The  swap file implementation in the kernel expects to be able to write
to the file directly, without the assistance of the  filesystem.   This
is  a problem on preallocated files (e.g.  fallocate(1)) on filesystems
like XFS or ext4, and on copy-on-write filesystems like btrfs.
```

It follows that, while `fallocate` may be faster than `dd`, it's not suitable for creating swap files and not supported by swap-related tools.

---

#### # # # # # ... ?

You should limit this to the width of the display (or default to 80, which is pretty common as a default width for terminals). There's no reason to have it extend beyond the visible width (and possibly wrap around). You can obtain the width from the `COLUMNS` special variable, and get a substring:

```
bash-4.4$ echo "$COLUMNS"
66
bash-4.4$ line="${line:0:$COLUMNS}"
bash-4.4$ echo "$line"
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

---

#### Prompts for `read`

A `echo -n "<prompt text>"` before `read` is unnecessary, as `read` has the `-p` option:

```
 -p PROMPT  output the string PROMPT without a trailing newline before
    attempting to read
```

---

#### Case-insensitive `case`

Use [the `nocasematch` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> If the `nocasematch` shell option (see the description of `shopt` in
>   [The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)) is enabled, the match is performed without regard
>   to the case of alphabetic characters.

So:

```
shopt -s nocasematch
case $yes_no in
    y|yes) ...
        ;;
    n|no|quit) ...
```

And so on.

This option also applies to the `==`/`!=`/`=~` tests in `[[ ... ]]`.

---

The `shopt -u extglob` is unnecessary.

---

#### Exit after `--help`

It's fairly standard to have commands exit without doing anything if asked to print help instead of continuing on to act on other options. And if you plan to extend it for non-interactive usage, then you'll likely add support for options as well. So you may want to print help for all unsupported options, and for options which were incorrectly given. So a new function:

```
usage() {
    echo "$help_text"
    exit "${1:-0}"  # default exit status 0 if `$1` isn't given
}
```

An example option would look like:

```
case $1 in
   -n)
      [[ -z $2 ]] && usage 1 # error: need a second arg with `-n`, so exit 1
      do_something with "$2"
      ;;
   -h|--help)
      usage  # asked for help, exit 0
      ;;
   -*) # error: unrecognized option, so exit 1
      usage 1
      ;;
esac
```

(Of course, if you do add more options, you should look into `getopts` for parsing them.)

---

> 1. Allow a non-interactive script mode that uses arguments for customizations
> 2. Allow single/batch removal of swapfiles.
> 3. Allow easier testing of each pathway of the interactive script

In that case, I'd **strongly** suggest that you extract out the actual actions (listing swap files, creating swap files, mounting them, etc.) into individual functions. This will allow you to mix and match actions based on options, allowing for easier testing and batch processing.

So the code might look like:

```
list_swapfiles() {
  printf "\n%s\n" "$line"
  printf "%s\n\n" "Current Swapfiles:"
  sudo swapon -s
  printf "\n%s\n" "$line"
}

# after parsing options
case $1 in)
  -l|--list)
    list_swapfiles
    exit
    ;;
  ...
esac

# no options, assume interactive
while true; do
  read -p ">>>> Are you sure you want to create a new swapfile? (Y / N):" yes_no
  case $yes_no in
    y|yes)       
      list_swapfiles
      break
      ;;
      ...
```

Comment: In addition to using the correct exit status, I'd also redirect `usage` to the standard error stream unless the help was requested: `usage 1 >&2`.

Comment: @muru What is the scope of the `shopt` commands? If I use a `shopt` command then will it go back to the original usage after my script ends? Or does the life of that `shopt` command continue after my script ends?

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski the scope of the `shopt` built-in is the shell in which it was ran, which is the shell that was started to execute the script. See also https://superuser.com/a/176788/334516

Comment: @muru I was looking at implementing your suggestions for the `read` command, and I say that people suggest to always use `read -r`. Do you also suggest that? My code does not disallow back-slashes for filenames.

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski I didn't notice you were reading filenames using `read`. In that case, please use [`IFS= read -r`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/70524).

Comment: @muru not sure if we mean the same thing, but I am allowing the user to define a filename for the swapfile. Regardless, it should only allow one line and the `\` allows multi-lines.

Comment: You pointed out a huge bug (I think) in my code with the use of `fallocate`, I am trying to figure out if I can convert to use `dd` while keeping my current user-facing interface. I have heard conflicting info on `bs` (block size). Some say it doesn't affect the disk at all and is only a convenience to creating a specific "allocation" size, while other posts state that it effects read and write speeds. Don't know what is true and don't know how I should proceed just yet.

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski it does affect speeds to some extent (which you can benchmark by yourself, varying bs and adjusting count accordingly). But you can also use `head -c` instead.

Answer (score 7):

#### Portability

You mentioned portability as one of your top concerns.
The commands used by the script limit it to certain systems:

- `swapon`, `mkswap`: these are common in Linux systems
- `fallocate`: available in Linux, supporting certain filesystems depending on the version
- `sudo`: available in a wide range of systems but not always installed by default

This script is not portable, and I think that's not a real concern.
It's designed to run in Linux systems with the supported filesystems.
I think it wouldn't make sense to try to make it "portable".

---

In less specialized scripts that conceptually could make sense in many systems,
using `echo -e` would be a portability concern.
`echo` without flags works reliably,
but its flags are not equally well supported in all systems.
It's best to write scripts in a way to use only `echo` without any flags.

#### Broken help message

This is clearly a bug:

> ```
> echo -e help_text
> ```

You probably intended this instead:

```
echo -e "$help_text"
```

And even then, the output would be pretty weird:

> ```
> /n>> Documentation:
>
>
>
> Usage: script.sh [-h]
>
> Creates a new permanent swapfile
>
>
> where:
>
>     -h  displays help text
> ```

Probably this is not what you intended.

#### Readability

I find the script very hard to read. For example this:

> ```
> help_text="/n>> Documentation:\n\n\t
>
> Usage: $(basename "$0") [-h]\n\t 
> Creates a new permanent swapfile\n\n\t
> where:\n\t\t
>     -h  displays help text"
> ```

Probably you intended something more like this:

```
help_text="
>> Documentation:

    Usage: $(basename "$0") [-h]
    Creates a new permanent swapfile

    where:
        -h  displays help text"
```

Which will output:

> ```
> >> Documentation:
>
>     Usage: a.sh [-h]
>     Creates a new permanent swapfile
>
>     where:
>         -h  displays help text
> ```

There is no need for escape sequences like `\n` and `\t`,
you can write them directly inside strings,
a lot easier to read,
and now you can `echo "$help_text"` without the `-e` flag and it just works.

#### Keep it simple

It's a good rule of thumb to keep things as simple as possible.
For example you used the `-e` in all `echo` statements,
even though most of them don't need it.
I suggest to question the purpose of every single element,
and cut out anything that isn't essential.

---

What is going on here?

> ```
> ?(-)@(-h|-help) )
> ```

Why not simply this:

```
-h|-help )
```

---

Some usability features can be simpler too.
For example:

> ```
> [Yy]|[Yy][Ee][Ss] )
> ```

How about like this instead:

```
[Yy]|yes|Yes )
```

The second is a lot easier to read.
Sure, it's not the same thing,
because the first version will match `yEs` too and the second won't.
But is that really a problem?

#### Quoting

One of the most important things to learn properly in Bash scripting is how quoting works.
It's not that complicated though.
Whenever you use a variable as command arguments,
they should be within double-quotes.

For example these statements are unsafe:

> ```
> case $1 in
>
> while $retry; do
> ```

They should be:

```
case "$1" in

while "$retry"; do
```

#### `sudo` in scripts

It's not great when a script needs to use `sudo`,
because it can be annoying to get prompted for a password unexpectedly.

This script cannot do anything useful without `sudo`.
It would be better to remove all the `sudo` from inside the script,
and make it required to call the script itself with `sudo`.
Add a simple check at the top of the script:

```
if [ "$(id -u)" != 0 ]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root or with sudo $0" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

#### Check yourself

There is a nice online service where you can paste your shell script and it points out bugs and safety issues, called [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/#).

Comment: Also, there is no `exit 0` with the help case. The idea behind `?(-)@(-h|-help)` is that will allow a user to type `-h`, `--h`, `-help`, or `--help` to get help. I have seen this double-hyphen usage for help quite a few times and wanted to emulate it somewhat. Do you think I should not do that?

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski wow. I didn't know it means that. It's not common to support both `-help` and `--help`. I suggest to stick to the GNU convention of `-h` and `--help`. That will be simpler. And simple is good.

Comment: I agree. I recently found that the convention for double-dash is to use a word or phrase (`--help`) and the single-dash is for a letter (`-h`). With that it is uncommon to see `--h` and `-help`. I didn't know that, so I will use your suggestion

Comment: can you please provide resources I can review for your comment `Whenever you use a variable as command arguments, they should be within double-quotes.` I don't understand when I should and shouldn't double-quote variables, and I don't fully understand why they are unsafe, yet.

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski see [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells). The long and short of quoting is: Always quote, unless you *know* you need the effects of unquoted expansion (which is almost never) (and even then, there might be better ways than unquoted expansion).

Comment: @janos where did you get the `fallocate` availability info from? The `fallocate(1)` manpage claims the syscall has been supported for ext4 and XFS since 2.6.31, and the command itself is lot older than Linux 3.14.

Comment: @muru that came from the manpage on my system, indeed that was too specific to mention without the source. Thanks, updated.

Comment: @janos if I put `#!/bin/bash` on the 1st line, then can other POSIX compliant shells run my script? I am looking at enforcing root and I noticed that there are fast bash-specific methods (`EUID`) and slower POSIX-compliant methods (`id -u`). Ultimately the speed doesn't matter, but if the `#!/bin/bash` declarative enforces bash, then a bash-specific might better?

Comment: @janos based on https://askubuntu.com/questions/141928/what-is-difference-between-bin-sh-and-bin-bash I believe my answer to my question is **no, other POSIX-compliant shells cannot run the script if you use `#!/bin/bash`, only bash can. Therefore it is safe to call bash-specific commands; however, if you want to be more portable, you should use `#!/bin/sh` and not use bash-specific commands.** Does that seem right?

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski with `#!/bin/bash` you can count on Bash features.